# clear last entry in calculator using C#

Tags: c#

I have a string;

```
string str = "3+4*2+8";
```

This string is entered by user..
I want to do an operation in which I just want to remove last entry of string. i.e 8 in this particular example.....
Please guide me how to do this....

Answer (score 3):

If all you're talking about are simple arithmetic expressions with positive integers, then you can probably use

```
Regex.Replace(str, @"([+*/-]|[0-9]+)$", "")
```

Testing:

```
PS Home:\> '3+4*2+8' -replace '([+*/-]|[0-9]+)$'
3+4*2+
PS Home:\> '3+4*2+' -replace '([+*/-]|[0-9]+)$'
3+4*2
PS Home:\> '1-42' -replace '([+*/-]|[0-9]+)$'
1-
```

Answer (score 0):

you can always find the last non digit char in the input and remove all the other chars from there
so basically :

- validate input...
- get last non digit char index
- return the string removing anything from that index

here is a very simple example

```
public static string TrimLastEntry(string text)
{
     // input is valid ?, check any additional rules of your own....
     if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(text))
     {
          return text;
     }

     // get last index of a non digit char
     int idx = text.Length - 1;
     for (; idx > 0; --idx)
     {
         if (!char.IsDigit(text[idx]))
         {
             break;
         }
     }

     // replace the last 
     return text.Remove(idx + 1);
}
```

this for sure will need more validation on the allowed inputs and their structure but should give you a starting point

- it could be only me but i have a little issue with variable that are named like common type names, IntelliSense completions gets annoying :)

Answer (score 0):

To remove the "last" entry, you need to define what the last entry is.

For instance, what is that "last" entry for `3*(1+2)`

Is is `2`, or `(1+2)`, or `*(1+2)`?

Are you going to have text in these expressions:

```
"Hello" + " " + "world!"
```

would be easy, but

```
"This is an expression: " + "1 + \"a\""
```

might be a bit more difficult to handle with regular expressions.

Back in the day, before XML, we had a tool that let you create lexical scanners so that you could create languages and then analyze or manipulate them. Check out [Flex](https://github.com/westes/flex/).

As usual, wikipedia has good entry on [Lexical Analysis](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexical_analysis).